# Android: MediaPlayer reloads remote resource

Tags: java, android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

i am using the MediaPlayer class to loop music from youtube. So far no problem, but the MediaPlayer downloads the video every playback again from youtube, which causes a lot of traffic. Is there a way to let the video in the buffer of the MediaPlayer?

I'm using the following code:

```
try {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource("http://r6---sn-4g57knsy.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?itag=18&key=yt5&ip=123.45.67.89&ipbits=0&ratebypass=yes&ms=au&source=youtube&sver=3&mt=1383664037&id=3fa390e8443132e0&expire=1383690428&sparams=gcr%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&fexp=935610%2C932206%2C916807%2C941242%2C916623%2C924616%2C907231%2C907240&mv=m&gcr=de&upn=9y98yq_WFEc&signature=98E548B5E368061D425FED483828E6D5AF1BBC2B.8AB359B7BA604F108D85578BC704844308E9B6EB");
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mp.prepare();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: write a simple proxy server to run on the device and cache it yourself. It's not incredibly hard, but it requires some thought to pull off seemlessly.